# "This script must be sourced, not executed. Run it like: source /bin/bash"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running a docker container, in which I am trying to source a *.sh* file.

To reproduce the experience, if you have docker, it's very easy:

```
$ docker run -i -t conda/miniconda3 /bin/bash

# apt-get update
# apt-get install git
# git clone https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan.git
# cd latplan
# source ./install.sh
```

Doing this, gives this error:

> This script must be sourced, not executed. Run it like: source /bin/bash

I have looked on other posts but I could not find a solution.

Any idea?

Many thanks!

[EDIT]

This is the begining of the *install.sh* file:

```
#!/bin/bash

env=latplan

# execute it in a subshell so that set -e stops on error, but does not exit the parent shell.
(
    set -e

    (conda activate >/dev/null 2>/dev/null)  || {
        echo "This script must be sourced, not executed. Run it like: source $0"
        exit 1
    }

    conda env create -n $env -f environment.yml || {
        echo "installation failed; cleaning up"
        conda env remove -n $env
        exit 1
    }

    conda activate $env

    git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: What kind of check is `install.sh` doing to determine it's being sourced or executed?

Comment: That's an unsound design. It assumes, falsely, that being executed rather than sourced into an interactive shell is the only way `conda activate` can fail. Digging into this requires reading the source code to the relevant version of `conda`, or tracing its execution (as with `set -x`).

Comment: Why use `set -e` if you are explicitly checking for, and exiting on, failed commands?

Comment: Anyhow, redirecting stderr away from `conda` is an incredibly bad idea here: it's preventing conda from writing an error message describing what _really_ went wrong, leaving only the message describing an incorrect assumption present in its place.

Comment: Running `conda activate` outside of the script may give you some insight into why it's failing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Have you not been paying attention to best practices in the industry over the last few decades?  Discarding relevant error messages and printing misleading, ambiguous, unhelpful messages to stdout is now mandatory.

Comment: ok, I just removed the 1st checking, and it's working fine

Comment: @ailauli69, maybe add your own answer with the "Add an Answer" button then?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I just removed the 1st checking, and it's working fine